# Release website via FTP on VSTS

Tags: ftp, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am using VSTS (VSO previously) to handle the entire project and would like to do automated releases (builds are already in place) of the website that is not hosted on Azure. Thus I need to use FTP.

As I understand it I should be able to use cURL to accomplish this, but all I have been able to do is transfer all files needed without keeping the much needed file structure.

Has anyone found a way to use FTP to transfer files in the file structure? And if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use "Batch Script" task and create a batch script to upload the files by curl. Refer to this question for details: [Upload folder with cURL and FTP using Batch file on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/590567/upload-folder-with-curl-and-ftp-using-batch-file-on-windows)

If your website is hosted on a Windows Machine, you can use "Windows Machine File Copy" task to upload the files. This task keeps the folder structure.
[image]

And also, you can generated web deploy packages during the build by adding following MSBuild arguments in "Visual Studio Build" task in the build definition and upload it to build artifact.

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"
```

Then in "Release", adding a task to run the "xxx.deploy.cmd" which is included in the build artifacts to deploy the files to your server. (Make sure your server has installed "Web Deploy Remote Agent Service")

```
xxx.deploy.cmd [/T|/Y] [/M:ComputerName] [/U:UserName] [/P:Password] [/G:UseTempAgent] [Additional msdeploy.exe flags ...]
```